# How to resize images automatically when uploading to WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The problem I'm having is with WooCommerce plugin in Wordpress. I am adding products along with their images but the problem is that the images I'm provided are of varying sizes. Some of the images are vertically oriented and as a result, the image gets cropped off so that only the top ~30% of the image is showing while the rest is cropped off.

I need to upload hundreds of product images so I'd want to find a way to efficiently resize everything properly so that images aren't cropped incorrectly. Do I just need to resize the images myself before uploading to WooCommerce or is there a way to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ultimately up to you how you want to handle your images - it's going to be specific to your site. That said WooThemes has some documentation on [using appropriate product image dimensions](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/using-the-appropriate-product-image-dimensions/). You might want to try unchecking "Hard crop" on the product thumbnails - this will result in your thumbnails not having the same dimensions but it will not crop part of the image. If this doesn't work, you probably need to pre-edit the images.